# How to fix OSD displaying weird symbols

Tags: betaflight, osd

I upgraded from betaflight 3.X to betaflight 4.1.X and now my OSD displays weird symbols.

It seems to have replaced the crosshair. (The 3 L shapes in the center)

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried going into BetaFlight and changing the OSD layout?

Comment: Which are the weird symbols? Most of those look perfectly normal?

Comment: You should be able to adjust/change the crosshair in the BetaFlight OSD settings.

Comment: Changing the crosshair position, disabling and re-enabling it didn't work. I had to reupload the font. Thanks!

Comment: per your follow up instructions, the copter needs to be powered up (lipo, not just USB) to upload and save the font, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it by re-uploading the font to the flight controller.

Some people report they need to power the quad with a LiPo for this to work. I did not need to.

1. Go to Betaflight's "OSD" tab
2. Click "Font Manager"
3. Click "Upload Font"

I'm now back with a normal crosshair.

As @3k pointed out,

> The reason for this is that the character set has changed between versions so it has to be updated on the copter.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. The reason for this is that the character set has changed between versions so it has to be updated on the copter

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit with your statement